# Load local data into IPython notebook server

Tags: server, ipython

I did setup an ipython server for other people (in my company department) to have a chance to learn and work with python.

Now I wonder how people can load their own local data into the ipython notebook session on the remote server. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which `IPython` version are you using? May be upgrade to `jupyter`

Comment: I'm using jupyter. So is there a way to upload data?

Comment: Just run `jupyter` from the directory (or its parent) you want the data from.

Comment: Well, the users don't have access to the server directories. They use only the web access to jupyter. Either the notebook would need the possibility to access the directories at the client computer, or the user needs the possibility to upload his data via the browser to the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have `jupyter` installed, all users should see the files/folders in the `jupyter` startup directory as well as its subdirectory. The `new` button on the `jupyter` notebook can be used to create a new file/folder or even a terminal.  Files can be uploaded using  drag-drop or `click here` feature highlighted below.

[image]

Comment: But how does this help me to upload data files?

Comment: @MichaelHecht - You can drag and drop files to notebook or browse to the file to be uploaded using the `click here`. See highlight in the updated screenshot.

Comment: Ah ... ok ... I'm the next few days not in the office, but I will check it as soon as possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well - it did work. Maybe this was too easy ant too abvious for me to see?! In Germany we say: You don't see the forrest because there are too many trees in front. Nevertheless, thank you for your kind assistance.

Comment: @Amit, how would you do this if you have tons of files you want to upload say 10k .txt files?

Comment: @mkheifetz Sorry I haven't tried it with so many files. I am guessing that the browser would hang with so many files. May be upload them directly using other utilities like ftp etc.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative way to achieve this with python:

```
def jupyter_upload(token, filePath, resourceDstPath, jupyterUrl='http://localhost:8888'):
    """
        Uploads File to Jupyter Notebook Server
        ----------------------------------------
        :param token:
            The authorization token issued by Jupyter for authentification 
            (enabled by default as of version 4.3.0)
        :param filePath:
            The file path to the local content to be uploaded

        :param resourceDstPath:
            The path where resource should be placed.
            The destination directory must exist.

        :param jupyterUrl:
            The url to the jupyter server. Default value is typical localhost installation.

        :return: server response

    """
    import os
    import base64
    import urllib
    import json
    import requests
    dstPath = urllib.quote(resourceDstPath)
    dstUrl = '%s/api/contents/%s' % (jupyterUrl, dstPath)
    fileName = filePath[1 + filePath.rfind(os.sep):]
    headers = {}
    headers['Authorization'] = 'token '+token
    with open(filePath, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
        b64data=base64.encodestring(data)
        body = json.dumps({
            'content':b64data,
            'name': fileName,
            'path': resourceDstPath,
            'format': 'base64',
            'type':'file'
        })
        return requests.put(dstUrl, data=body, headers=headers, verify=True)
```

Comment: I'm having a problem, i get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

My jupyter notebook is running on a remote server, and i want to upload a file from my laptop. @volhv

Answer (score 1):

Once you run `jupyter` ipython notebook, click on **new** --> Go to `terminal` and then simply run the following command :

[image: You can pass your files **url** here and get your file uploaded on the server and you are ready to go. Otherwise directly drag a file or upload the file from the <code>upload</code> button.]

You can pass your files **url** here and get your file uploaded on the server and you are ready to go. Otherwise directly drag a file or upload the file from the `upload` button.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a text file, create a empty file, edit it and then copy/paste the content..

You can do this to bypass the 25mb constraint