# Add modules to Jupyterhub

Tags: python, jupyterhub

I would like to make use some of my own python modules in a notebook that's sitting on a remote jupyterhub server.

How can I go about uploading the module onto the remote server? And if necessary, configure the import scope?

EDIT:
For some more clarity:
I would like to have my packages to be uploaded and stored in a user environment, eg: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/my-packages/'
and access them via imports in the notebook.

Comment: Do you start your notebook via JupyterHub and try to import your own module inside the notebook?

Comment: Yes. So I have some existing modules that are stored on my local machine. And I would like to use them via import inside a notebook via JupyterHub.

Comment: You can upload your module (.py) file via the webpage. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29988225/6238076) is a demonstration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load local data into IPython notebook server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968829/load-local-data-into-ipython-notebook-server)

Comment: @gdlmx, many thanks for the suggestions. Please see my edit for added clarifications to what it is that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Jupyter hub allows multiple users to login. Would you like other users to be able to use your module? Note that "user environment" you mentioned is still a system path requiring some superuser permissions to install. If you have multiuser requirements, you'll need such superuser rights on the remote server. If there is just one jupyter hub user on the remote machine, there are more optins to install a module w/o a superuser priviledges

Comment: @ArtemTrunov - will have use cases for both. Some modules are shared across users while others are for self use during the prototyping stage. Can you please share both? Thanks very much.

Comment: To put any file under the path `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/my-packages/`, you need the privilege to run `sudo` command on the remote machine. You can start a terminal (in Jupyter or via SSH) and try to run some `sudo` commands there.

Comment: If you're not the administrator for your JupyterHub+Linux server system, you have to ask the admin to install any global package. Do not bother to do it on your own.