# How do I programmatically upload files to JupyterLab from my local storage?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I was wondering if JupyterLab has an API that allows me to programmatically upload files from my local storage to the JupyterLab portal. Currently, I am able to manually select "Upload" through the UI, but I want to automate this.

I have searched their documentation but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I am using a chromebook (if that matters). 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can use python packages "requests" and "urllib" to upload files
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41915132/11845699
This method is actually the same as clicking the upload button, but the uploading speed is not very satisfying so I don't recommend it if you are uploading lots of files or some large files.

I don't know whether your JupyterLab server is managed by your administrator or yourself. In my case, I'm the administrator of the server in my lab. So I setup an NFS disk and mount it to a folder in the JupyterLab working directory. The users can access to this NFS disk via our local network or the internet. NFS disk is capable of transmitting lots of large files, which is much more efficient than the Jupyter upload button. I learned this from a speech of a TA in Berkeley https://bids.berkeley.edu/resources/videos/teaching-ipythonjupyter-notebooks-and-jupyterhub

I highly recommend this if you can contact the person who has access to the file system of your Jupyter server. If you don't use Linux, then Webdav is an alternative to NFS. Actually, anything that can give you access to a folder on a remote server is optional, such as Nextcloud or Pydio.

(If you can't ask the administrator to deploy such service, then just use the python packages)